# Duplication involving SUM, LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem involving a SUM, LEFT OUTER JOIN and GROUP BY commands, but can't figure out where my error is.

I have two tables, one for customer transactions and one for customer claims. A customer can have multiple transactions and multiple claims, but in both tables the rows are unique. Customers can also have no claims.

Example transactions table:

```
Transactions:
Customer | Transaction Year | Amount
-------------------------------------
A        | 2007             | 100
A        | 2008             | 80
A        | 2008             | 50
A        | 2009             | 210
```

Example claims table:

```
Claims:
Customer | Claim Year | Amount
-------------------------------
A        | 2007       | 30
A        | 2007       | 40
A        | 2009       | 110
```

The desired output is to sum the two amounts, and produce a row for each unique combination of Customer and Year.

```
Desired Output:
Customer | Year | Transaction Amount | Claim Amount
----------------------------------------------------
A        | 2007 | 100                | 70
A        | 2008 | 130                | NULL
A        | 2009 | 210                | 110
```

I have used a LEFT OUTER JOIN command with a GROUP BY command for the Customer and Year values. But what I am getting is a duplication of the Transaction Amount value, and the multiple relates to the number of matching rows in the Claims table.

So using my example data I get the following:

```
Actual Output:
Customer | Year | Transaction Amount | Claim Amount
----------------------------------------------------
A        | 2007 | 200                | 70
A        | 2008 | 130                | NULL
A        | 2009 | 210                | 110
```

In the year 2007, there are two claims which has resulted in the Transactions.Amount value being multiplied by two (when there are three claims, the Transaction.Amount is tripled, etc).

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT Transactions.Customer,
   Transactions.Year,
   sum(Transactions.Transaction Amount),
   sum(Claims.Claim Amount)
FROM Transactions
   LEFT JOIN Claims ON Claims.Customer = Transactions.Customer
      AND Transactions.Year = Claims.Year
GROUP BY Transactions.Customer, Transactions.Year
```

Does the answer lie in subqueries? I am not familiar with them, so any pointers would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try putting a distinct clause ?

Comment: DISTINCT will not change the result, as it works across rows of the result table (which are distinct now), not columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the first step to see what is happening is to remove the SUMs and just select the transaction amount and claim amount. That way you can see what data is being returned. You'll see that the join on A/2007 will have the transaction amount twice, since it's joining each row to the claims table.

One solution is to use subquerys, like you said, to do the SUMs separately prior to joining.

```
SELECT 
   Transactions.Customer,
   Transactions.Year,
   SumTransaction,
   SumClaim
FROM (
      select Customer, Year, sum(Transaction Amount) SumTransaction 
      from Transactions
      group by Customer, Year
   ) Transactions
   LEFT JOIN (
      select Customer, Year, sum(Claim Amount) sumClaim 
      from Claims
      group by Customer, Year
   ) Claims
   ON Claims.Customer = Transactions.Customer
      AND Transactions.Year = Claims.Year
```

Another possible solution given your restrictions:

```
SELECT 
   Transactions.Customer,
   Transactions.Year,
   SUM(Transaction Amount),
   (SELECT SUM(Claim Amount) from Claims where Claims.Customer = Transactions.Customer and Claims.Year = Transactions.Year)
FROM 
   Transactions
GROUP BY
   Customer, Year
```

Third possible solution!! This one does not require any subqueries! See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1865/1/0)

```
select
    t.Customer,
    t.Year,
    sum(distinct t.Amount),
    sum(c.Amount)
from
    Transactions t
    left join Claims c
        on  t.Customer = c.Customer
            and t.Year = c.year
group by
    t.Customer,
    t.Year
```

Comment: You forgot to `group by` in the sub-queries

Comment: To see what is happening I also had to remove the GROUP BY statements.

Your solution might work... if I wasn't restricted by my application. I am using Zoho Reports, which does not currently support SELECT query in FROM clause - annoying.

Any ideas for a solution not using subqueries?

Comment: Are you able to use subqueries in the select list? See the edit above for a possible solution...

Comment: I actually just tested another solution that works without the need for subqueries! See the edit/SQL Fiddle :)

Comment: Second solution didn't work - it is being picked up as a column title (I have the comma!)... trying the third...

Comment: We are close! The third solution works very well.

There is an issue with duplicate rows. The real Transaction and Claim tables contain more columns than I have shown above. In the sample tables, there are a few rows that are not unique.

I thought I just needed to add a unique identifier from each table to the GROUP BY statement, but this has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

The query will be counting the transaction amount twice for 2007 due to the fact you have two claims, so the transaction amount will be counted twice.

i.e. the returned data being used is:

```
Customer | Transaction Year | Transaction Amount | Claim Amount
----------------------------------------------------------------
A        | 2007             | 100                | 30
A        | 2007             | 100                | 40
A        | 2008             | 80                 |
A        | 2008             | 50                 |
A        | 2009             | 210                | 110
```

Something like the following, although not pretty, should resolve the problem:

```
SELECT 
   t.Customer
   ,t.Year
   ,[Transaction Amount] = SUM(t.[Transaction Amount])
   ,[Claim Amount] = c.[Claim Amount]
FROM 
    Transactions t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            Customer
            ,Year
            ,SUM([Claim Amount])
        FROM
           Claims
        GROUP BY
           Customer, Year
    ) c ON c.Customer = t.Customer c.Year = t.Year
GROUP BY t.Customer, t.Year, c.[Claim Amount]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
With T as (
    SELECT  Customer,
            [Transaction Year],
            sum(Amount) AS TransactionAmount
    FROM Transactions
    GROUP BY Customer, [Transaction Year]
), C AS 
    SELECT  Customer,
            [Claim Year],
            sum(Amount) as ClaimAmount
    FROM Claims
    GROUP BY Customer, [Claim Year]
)
SELECT  T.Customer,
        [Transactions Year],
        TransactionAmount,
        ClaimAmount
FROM    T
   LEFT JOIN C ON C.Customer = T.Customer
      AND [Transactions Year] = [Claim Year]
```

Comment: This is tagged as MySql, which doesn't have CTE functionality.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize.